# What Graph DB to use in Bluemix now that IBM Graph is deprecated?

Tags: graph, ibm-cloud

Looking at IBM Graph in Bluemix, I see this is marked as "Deprecated"..but there is not mention of what to use in its place.  I see there is "Compose for JanusGraph" but not sure if that is what will be replacing "IBM Graph" or if there is a better/more comparable option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer [here](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2017/10/retirement-of-ibm-graph/):

Looks like the replacement for IBM Graph is Compose for JanusGraph.